# state variable resetting itself for no re

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a React Component that includes a list of items. When the user double clicks an item, a new browser window opens that allows the user to edit the item. The opener (the component that opens the new browser window) needs to keep track of all the browser windows that it has opened and when they close. This is needed so that if the user double clicks an item that has already been opened, I can give focus to the existing window for that item rather than opening a new one. I'm trying to keep track of the open windows in a state variable. Here is the relevant code:-

```
const handleSalesItemDoubleClick = (salesItem) => {
        var windowRef = window.open(process.env.REACT_APP_APP_SERVER + '/' + site.SiteCode + '/SalesItem/' + salesItem,
            salesItem,
            'width=1000,left=0,top=0,height=600,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no'
        )
        windowRef.onload = function () {
            windowRef.onbeforeunload = () => { handleWindowClose(salesItem) }
        }
        var tabs = [...openSalesItems, {salesItem: salesItem, window: windowRef}];
        setOpenSalesItems(tabs);
    }

    const handleWindowClose = (salesItemId) => {
        var tabs = openSalesItems.filter(function (tab) { return tab.salesItem !== salesItemId })
        setOpenSalesItems(tabs);
    }
```

setOpenSalesItems is the function that sets the state variable "openSalesItems".

When I open multiple new windows then close them in reverse order, the openSalesItems contains the correct array at all times but if I open multiple windows then close the window that I opened first, the openSalesItems array becomes empty.

Comment: When closing the first opened, what is the return of salesItemId in handleWindowClose  function and the content of openSalesItems before setOpenSalesItems(tabs)?

Comment: The salesItemId is correct (refers to the first opened) but the content of openSalesItems is [] even as it enters handleWindowClose